# How to regex match all cases

Tags: regex

I've always found constructing RegEx to be quite confusing. I am trying to construct one to catch all variations of the form:

```
(82.39%)
(18%)
(100%)
(9.0%)
(90.2%)
(5%)
(59.2857%)
(5.45%)
```

This is what I currently have but I don't seem to catch all cases:

```
\(\d+\.?\d+?\%\)
```

I cannot match e.g. `(5%)` and `(90.2%)`

Comment: Do you wish to match `(082.39%)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use regex pattern

```
\(\d+(?:\.\d+)?%\)
```

https://regex101.com/r/b927H7/1